# Python. How to find a point in the stretch(line segment) 2D?

Tags: python, math

There are two points in 2D

```
point1 = (x1, y1)
point2 = (x2, y2)
```

There is stretch between those two points:

```
stretch = math.hypot(x2 - x1, y2 - y1)
```

How to find point (x3, y3) anywhere in that strech?

Comment: I think you want interpolation. Try searching for that.

Comment: Please elaborate, you need a point which is "m" distance from (x1,y1)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you call "stretch" is a [line segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_segment), and you compute its norm (or length, if you will) with [`math.hypot`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.hypot)

For any `t` between 0 and 1, the point `(x1 + t*(x2-x1), y1 + t*(y2-y1))` is part of the line segment. In particular, with `t = 0` your point will be the `(x1,y1)` and  with `t = 1` your point will be the `(x2,y2)`.

If you use a `t` value outside of the interval `[0,1]` then you will have a point on the same line but outside of the segment.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get some point lying on P1P2 segment, you can use equations of linear interpolation:

```
x3 = x1 + t * (x2 - x1)
y3 = y1 + t * (y2 - y1)
```

where `t` is in range 0..1